# Adding images pixel by pixel in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a function that would take images uploaded by user (`values` argument is an array of Files) and add them up pixel by pixel. The page freezes. Is this function ok?

```
function addImages(values) {
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d', { willReadFrequently: true });
const loadPromises = [];
values.forEach((value) => {
    const image = new Image();
    image.src = URL.createObjectURL(value);
    const loadPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        image.onload = () => {
            URL.revokeObjectURL(image.src);
            resolve(image);
        }
        image.onerror = () => {
            URL.revokeObjectURL(image.src);
            reject(new Error('Image loading failed.'));
        }
    });
    loadPromises.push(loadPromise);
})
Promise.all(loadPromises).then(images => {
    const widths = images.map(i => i.width);
    const heights = images.map(i => i.height);
    canvas.width = Math.max(...widths);
    canvas.height = Math.max(...heights);
    const resultData = ctx.createImageData(canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (let i = 0; i < resultData.data.length; i += 4) {
        images.forEach(image => {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
            const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            resultData.data[i] += imageData.data[i];
            resultData.data[i + 1] += imageData.data[i + 1];
            resultData.data[i + 2] += imageData.data[i + 2];
        })
    }
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.putImageData(resultData, 0, 0);
    return canvas.toDataURL();
});}
```

Comment: You seem to have gone for a very sub-optimal approach here,  I would loop the images then loop the image data, also your just adding the images together, this will just end up making the image whiter the more images you add, did you mean to average the images together.?

Comment: its just an incredibly slow way of doing it, for each pixel that you sum, you clear the canvas, load the image onto the canvas, read the pixel, you should process each image in turn rather than pixel by pixel, so load the image, scan the image adding the pixels, then load the next image, scan the image etc

Comment: what's the value of  `images.length * canvas.width * canvas.height`? that's how many times you `clearRect`, `drawImage`, and `getImageData`

Comment: i dont want to add any answers here because im tired of getting downvoted for trying to help people out, here is a codepen so you can see whats going on, i'll post another codepen with a the quicker version in a mo https://codepen.io/matt-2016/pen/vYvabZq

Comment: if you `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";` then `images.forEach(image => ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0));` - the result should be the same as what your for loop is doing - though, not identical, since your current code can overflow the pixel values, not sure if that's central to your code or not

Comment: ok here is the quicker version https://codepen.io/matt-2016/pen/oNJMmqO, but dont add more than 2 images else they will white out

Comment: @mattrichards - `ImageData.data` is described as `a one-dimensional array containing the data in the RGBA order` - i.e. 4 values per pixel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to achieve the same result by using `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";` then simply adding the images to the canvas one by one

This results in a speedup of, well, it's hard to calculate almost instant vs multiple minutes for even image sizes of less than 100x100 pixels - let's just call the improvement in speed *significant*

Note: the only thing I'm not sure about is what happens in your code when values "overflow" (i.e. > 255) in your code - but, I haven't the patience to run your code :p

```js
function addImages(values) {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d', {
    willReadFrequently: true
  });
  const loadPromises = [];
  values.forEach((value) => {
    const image = new Image();
    image.src = URL.createObjectURL(value);
    const loadPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      image.onload = () => {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(image.src);
        resolve(image);
      }
      image.onerror = () => {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(image.src);
        reject(new Error('Image loading failed.'));
      }
    });
    loadPromises.push(loadPromise);
  })
  return Promise.all(loadPromises)
    .then(images => {
      const widths = images.map(i => i.width);
      const heights = images.map(i => i.height);
      canvas.width = Math.max(...widths);
      canvas.height = Math.max(...heights);
      const resultData = ctx.createImageData(canvas.width, canvas.height);
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
      images.forEach(image => ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0));
      return canvas.toDataURL();
    });
}
const input = document.querySelector('#files');
const image = document.querySelector('#target');
input.addEventListener('change', async() => {
  const url = await addImages([...input.files]);
  image.src = url;
});
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="files" type="file" multiple/>
</div>

<img id="target" />
```

Comment: thank you for such a nice explanation, i see now that the for/foreach loops were executed in a very unproductive manner. and i didn't even know about globalCompositeOperation. wish you all the best

Comment: @peppap1g - not sure what your end goal is, but play around with the `globalCompositeOperation` values - `multiply` gives a nice blend of multiple images